# AutoComplete comJQuery querie Estruturada

Tags: c#, jquery, autocompletar

Precisava fazer uma query que funcionasse como o seguinte exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No print pode ver que digitando um item,retorna estruturado por bairro e depois cidade.

Eu queria poder saber como fazer minha query desta maneira, estruturada por Bairro, Cidade e Rua. Apenas consigo implementar a forma simples e vincula-lo a TextBox, de acordo com o arquivo a seguir:

```
public class AutocompleteData : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
string firstname = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
string sql = "SELECT Bairro FROM [Bairro] where Bairro like '" + Bairro + 
"%' ; ";
string conexao = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ctString"].ToString();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conexao))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();     
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                context.Response.Write(reader[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```